# How do I add a subview to UIStatusBar in Theos?

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, theos, logos

I know it sounds like this question has a simple answer, but hear me out. Although `UIStatusBar` is a subclass of `UIView`, you can't use the `addSubview` method to add a subview to it because it doesn't use it. The same goes for `UIStatusBarWindow`. Neither the view or window have a viewcontroller, so I can't hook into that in any way.

Here is the relevant section of code. The line where I call the `addSubviews` method on self is the issue, because `addSubviews` isn't a method of `UIStatusBar`.

```
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>

@interface UIStatusBar : UIView
@end

%hook UIStatusBar
- (void)layoutSubviews {
  //Round corners under status bar
  CGFloat radius = 15;
  CGRect wholeScreen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
  UIView *roundedCorners = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(-radius, 20-radius, wholeScreen.size.width+2*radius, wholeScreen.size.height-20+2*radius)];
  roundedCorners.layer.borderWidth = radius;
  roundedCorners.layer.cornerRadius = 2*radius;
  roundedCorners.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor.CGColor;
  roundedCorners.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
  [self addSubView:roundedCorners];
}
%end
```

Is there another way I can add the subview? The reason I'm trying to do it this way is so that, whenever the status bar is hidden, my `roundedCorners` view is also hidden. I could hide it whenever the status bar is hidden, but due to different apps using many different methods of hiding the status bar that doesn't work out as well as I hoped.

Answer (score 2):

I think a solution here is to use the notifications delivered whenever the status bar's height changes.

Using either/both:

[`UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationwillchangestatusbarframenotification?language=objc)

[`UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrameNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdidchangestatusbarframenotification?language=objc)

or you can also use the `AppDelegate` methods that get called when the status bar changes frame:

[`-application:willChangeStatusBarFrame:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623020-application?language=objc)

[`-application:didChangeStatusBarFrame:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622943-application?language=objc)

You can in these methods adjust your rounded corners according to the status bar's new frame. Hopefully this solves you problem!